# how to use "for loop" to write multiple .csv file names?

Tags: r, csv, for-loop

Does anyone know the best way to carry out a "for loop" that would read in different subject id's and append them to the name of an exported csv?

As an example, I have multiple output files from an electrocardiogram software program (each file belongs to one individual). The files are named C800_HR.bdf.evt, C801_HR.bdf.evt, C802_HR.bdf.evt etc. Each file gets read into r and then has a script applied to calculate heart rate variability. At the end of the script, I need to add a loop that will extract the subject id (e.g., C800, C801, C802) and write a new file name for each individual so that it becomes C800_RtoR.csv. Essentially, I would like to avoid changing the syntax every time I read in and export a file name.

I am currently using the following syntax to read in multiple files:

```
>setwd("/Users/kmpc/Downloads")
>myhrvdata <-lapply(Sys.glob("C8**_HR.bdf.evt"), read.delim)
```

Comment: Try `paste0(substr(1, 4, x), "_RtoR.csv")` where `x` contains your file names.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
cardio_files <- list.files(pattern = "C8\\d{2}_HR.bdf.evt")
subject_ids <- sub("^(C8\\d{2})_.*", "\\1" cardio_files)

myList <- lapply(cardio_files, read.delim)


## do calculations on the list

for (i in names(myList)) {

  write.csv(myList[[i]], paste0(subject_ids[i], "_RtoR.csv"))

}
```

The only thing is, you have to deal with using a list when doing your calculations. You could combine them to a single data.frame, but it would be best to leave it as a list to write the files at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Consider generalizing your process by creating a function that: 1) reads in file, 2) processes data, 3) outputs to csv. Then have `lapply` call the defined method iteratively across all `Sys.glob` items and even return a list of calculated data frames.

```
proc_heart_rate <- function(f_name) {
   # READ IN .evt FILE INTO df
   df <- read.delim(f_name)

   # CALCULATE HEART RATE VARIABILITY WITH df
   ...

   # OUTPUT df TO CSV
   subject_id <- gsub("\\_.*", "", f_name)
   write.csv(df, paste0(subject_id, "_RtoR.csv"))

   # RETURN df FOR OTHER USES
   return(df)
}

# LIST OF DATA FRAMES WITH CALCULATIONS
myhrvdata_list <-lapply(Sys.glob("C8**_HR.bdf.evt"), proc_heart_rate)
```